# Object variable independence

Tags: java, class, object, static, instance

Recreating pokemon in java, but having a small issue

For some reason, when assigning the same instance of a Move object to two different Pokemon, when one Pokemon uses that move, the PP value for the other Pokemon's move goes down by one as well when they should be independent of one another. I've done a lot of self-teaching and up to this point, I thought that static variables were used when wanting to achieve something like that, but I'm not using any statics here so I'm not sure why its happening. Do I need to create different instances of the same move to avoid this or is there a simpler way for the Move's variables to be independent when they belong to two separate 'Pokemon' objects? I've included some of the code for my Move class below.

```
public class Move
{
    private final String name;
    private final String type;
    private int damage;
    private double accuracy;
    private int powerPoints;
    private int maxPowerPoints;
    private boolean priority; // label for speed priority
    private boolean physical; // physical label
    private boolean special; // special label
}
```

Comment: That is only the definition of the move class. For your problem it would be important to see the instantiation and use of the move object. Please create a [mcve]. To do so, spend some time on minimising the code necessary to demonstrate the problem you are observing.

Comment: There's a delete button underneath the post.

Comment: Doesn't let me delete it since there's a response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to create different instances of the same move to avoid this
>   or is there a simpler way for the Move's variables to be independent
>   when they belong to two separate 'Pokemon' objects?

Yes, you should create a new instance. 
Read more about references in java i.e. here http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174371&seqNum=4

Comment: Helpful read! Thanks! Do you think would it be ideal in the future when having to create many instances of the same move to learn how to use a factory instead?

Comment: I am not really aware about the battle system for pokemons, but definitely you could benefit from using factory or prototype patterns.